# how can I use OPEN SURF in python without using open CV?

Tags: python, opencv, surf

I am a newbie to image processing in python .I want to use SURF in python for matching images.  Everywhere i searched I got its implemetation using OPENCV only . Is there a way I can use it without using Open CV

Comment: You could try [mahotas](http://pythonhosted.org/mahotas/surf.html) instead. Is there a reason you wish to avoid OpenCV?

Comment: sorry to ask, but what is the problem with opencv surf?

Comment: I already implemented it with opencv , just that my instructed wanted me to see if there is a way without using opencv. Anyways,thanks friends